# WCF with Android and IOS compatibilities

Tags: c#, wcf

I am planning to develop a WCF application to communicate with WP8, android and IOS.

Will I have any big problems communicating with the API of these operating systems?

For example, I am planning to build a fuel gas app with many gas stations in it. The user can vote for each gas station and take all the current prices from the WCF app database. The WCF will send the gas prices every day to the apps and will receive the likes for any gas station.

Also i was wondering because of the data exchange will be small. would be a good idea to use  TCP/Sockets communication between the apps and the server ? or it is a bad idea because i have done that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF returns XML or JSON format.  There is no issues from XML or JSON in any platforms.

Comment: So i will not face any problem calling the WCF with android or Ios ?? and get or sent the data i want ?

Comment: WCF service call using URL.  You want to call in application in android or iOS. If so, there is no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. i am planning to have all the infos of the stations in the phones and just litle data to be exhanged such as prices. i want to minimize the amount of data transfer via internet and also make the app usefull when it is offline. of course if i have all the gas station inforamtion inside tha apps and exchange a litle amount of data i think is a good solution